# What *isn't* Typeable in GHC 7.8?

Tags: haskell, reflection, ghc

I'm working with the author of [syntactic](https://github.com/emilaxelsson/syntactic/issues/8) to add support for a wide variety of types. I proposed using type lists to allow *any* type to be used, the dev proposed a cleaner solution that allows use with any instance of `Typeable`.

I know (at least the current version) of `Data.Reflection` [doesn't support `Typeable` reified types](https://github.com/ekmett/reflection/issues/14) in GHC 7.8, but at least they proposed a workaround using `lens`.

My question is about the original proposal for the library: aside from (some forms of) reified types, what other types in GHC 7.8 *cannot* be made an instance of `Typeable`? If these types are sufficiently strange/rare, it could suffice to use the clean solution that requires `Typeable`, but if there are [other] commonly used types that aren't `Typeable`, the type list would be the more general solution.

Comment: @JBerryman Although your answer didn't directly answer the question, it was contributing to the discussion (and I was learning a lot from the comments). I'd encourage you to put it back up, because I can't see any of the discussion now.

Comment: [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TXcdT.png) is an image of the deleted answer and the comments...

Comment: @MattDMo Thanks! Looks like I misremembered the OP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GHC.TypeLits.Symbol` and `Nat` are not Typeable. See https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9111

Comment: Hrm, I was under the mistaken impression that `Nat` *was* `Typeable`. This is problematic since I was using `Nat` and reified types as a phantom type parameter. I thought using `Nat` would help, but it *still* leaves my concrete type un-`Typeable`.

Answer (score 1):

`Typeable` breaks abstraction of data types: the concrete structure of anything `Typeable` can be queried even if it's constructors are hidden.

Most dangerously this means that types constructed via `Typeable` leak information which may lead to improper use.

So, generally, types which are to be thought of as abstract cannot be `Typeable`. A similar game and dance is played with role annotations since `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` is a kind of reflection.

Comment: Huh?  Are you sure you're not thinking of `Data`, rather than `Typeable`?

Comment: Data would be worse, but I'm pretty sure Typeable has all the same weaknesses.

Comment: I see nothing in [the docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html) that leads me to believe `Typeable` can be used to create values of types that are instances of it.

Comment: Sorry, you're right about construction. I'll edit the answer. The problem still remains in that you can reflect information out of "abstract" types even if you cannot construct them.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "types constructed via Typeable"? Do you have any concrete examples of "types which are to be thought of as abstract" which cannot be made Typeable (safety aside)?

Comment: Indeed, `Typeable` breaks the usual "free theorems". For instance, `f :: a->a` has to be the identity or the constant bottom function. Instead, `f :: Typeable a => a->a` can behave as the identity except when `a=Int`, in which case it behaves as `succ`.

Comment: @chi That's a useless objection, though. All type classes break free theorems. Free theorems only apply to parametric polymorphism, and type classes are bounded polymorphism.

Comment: I was curious about the current state of `Typeable`, and found this bug on GHC's trac: [9111](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9111). It suggests that sufficiently far in the future, GHC might just generate `Typeable` instances for everything automatically. This suggests that at least Edward Kmett doesn't see any danger in having them. (I mention him specifically because he explicitly said something about it.)

Comment: @Carl This wouldn't actually get a `Typeable` instance for reified types though, would it?

Comment: I think I'm just going to delete this answer. I posed it suggestively, but really it's more speculative than substantial.